# How to use filter operation while databinding

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I am using virtual scrolling on the grid. I want my grid should support filtering operation too to achieve this can i make use of FilterParameterName="" &  FilterParameterType="" properties of databinding or is there any other way available to achieve filtering with virtual scrolling.

```
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="SUPPNAME" HeaderText="Name" UniqueName="suppName" />

                    </Columns>
                </MasterTableView>
                <ClientSettings>
                    <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" EnableVirtualScrollPaging="True" UseStaticHeaders="True">
                    </Scrolling>
                    <DataBinding Location="POProcessing.aspx" SelectMethod="GetProductData" SelectCountMethod="GetCount"
                        StartRowIndexParameterName="startRowIndex" MaximumRowsParameterName="maxRows" FilterParameterName="suppName" FilterParameterType="String" />
                    <ClientEvents OnCommand="showLoadingPanel" OnDataBound="hideLoadingPanel" OnRowClick="onRowClick"
                        OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound" OnRowSelecting="OnRowSelecting" OnRowDeselecting="OnRowDeselecting" />
                    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="true" />
                </ClientSettings>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply filters through the grid columns filter textboxes, I suppose it will be retained after virtual scrolling processing. The DataBinding > FilterParameterName/FilterParameterType attributes can most likely be used to specify name and type for the filter parameter that will be passed to the Select method by default.